# Could not load file or assembly \\bin\\bin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Initially project output path was "bin\debug" and error was showing `ould not load file or assembly \\bin\\debug\\bin\\` then I changed to output path to `bin\` and now it showing `{"Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\\username\\Trunk\\Source\\projectdir\\bin\\bin\\TIMSS.API.UserSPE.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"file:///C:\\username\Trunk\\Source\\projectdir\\bin\\bin\\TIMSS.API.UserSPE.dll"}`

again i changed to output path to `.`(just dot) application is working fine but on build all assemblies are creating on root dir. I didn't understand how to resolve this.

When I set output directory to `bin\`. I can see all assemblies in bin directory. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear, something cannot be loaded when the pgm. is run.  But finding the root cause is not as simple.  There is a tool you can download to see Assembly loading failures See link below.  This then gives you the ability to gain a bit more information.

NOTE: This issue may not just be with the DLL being shown above, but it could also be some other DLLs it refers to are not being found. To find the full story you have to break out ILDASM and look at the DLL manifest of the suspected problem child.

But first start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx